# Staircase problem solved using recursion

Tags: python, programming-challenge, recursion, combinatorics

## Problem

Question taken from [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa14/disc/disc03.pdf).

> I want to go up a flight of stairs that has n steps. I can either take 1 or 2 steps each time. How many different ways can I go up this flight of stairs? Write a function `count_stair_ways` that solves this problem for me.
> `def count_stair_ways(n):`

## Solution:

```
def count_stair_ways(n):
    if n == 1: # 1 way to flight 1 stair case step
        return 1
    if n ==2: # 2 ways to flight 2 stair case steps(1+1, 2)
        return 2
    return count_stair_ways(n-1) + count_stair_ways(n-2)
```

Can we improve this code?

Comment: Is this quicker than a `for i in range(n)` construction?

Answer (score 9):

The staircase problem actually just generates the Fibonnacci sequence.

Whilst the recursive solution is nice, without memoization you're much better off just using a loop:

```
def count_stairways(n):

   a, b = 0, 1
   for _ in range(n):
       a, b = b, a+b

   return b
```

A nice alternative if you want multiple values out is to create a generator:

```
def count_stairways():

    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        a, b = b, a+b
        yield b
```

If you just want a particular value (possibly for a large n), the fibonnacci sequence actually has a closed form

```
 def count_stairways(n):

     phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2

     return int((pow(phi, n+1) - pow(1-phi, n+1))/math.sqrt(5))
```

Comment: +1 As with many problems, they can be reduced to something simpler and well understood.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is easy to understand and just works but it can still be improved.

**Documentation**

It could be nice to add some documentation to tell which values are expected.

**Domain**

When I tried with `0` as an input, I got a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. This is because the recursion calls go deeper and deeper into negative numbers without reaching a stop.

Adding :

```
if n < 0:
    return 0
if n == 0:
    return 1
```

just solves this problem. By the way, there is 1 way to flight a 0 stair case step.

**Tests**

It is a good habit to add tests for your code. I won't dive into testing framework and everything but just adding :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n, value in enumerate([1, 1 ,2 ,3 ,5 ,8 ,13 ,21 ,34 ,55]):
        res = count_stair_ways(n)
        assert res == value, "exp:%d got:%d for n = %d" % (value, res, n)
```

gives you a nice way to see if things ever go wrong.

**Keep it simple**

Once you handle all `n <= 0`, you don't need to handle the cases 1 and 2 individually. You can remove :

```
if n == 1: # 1 way to flight 1 stair case step
    return 1
if n ==2: # 2 ways to flight 2 stair case steps(1+1, 2)
    return 2
```

and see that it still works fine.

At this point, the code becomes :

```
def count_stair_ways(n):
    """ Some doc. Input can be any integer n."""
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return count_stair_ways(n-1) + count_stair_ways(n-2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n, value in enumerate([1, 1 ,2 ,3 ,5 ,8 ,13 ,21 ,34 ,55]):
        res = count_stair_ways(n)
        assert res == value, "exp:%d got:%d for n = %d" % (value, res, n)
```

**Performance**

Your solution will be slow for any big (or even medium) inputs. You can easily see add a print statement at the beginning of the function to see how many times it gets called and you'll see that we compute the same things many times.

When n is 15, the function gets called that many times with the different inputs :

```
610 -1
987 0
610 1
377 2
233 3
144 4
 89 5
 55 6
 34 7
 21 8
 13 9
  8 10
  5 11
  3 12
  2 13
  1 14
  1 15
```

There must be a better way.
Using memoization is the way to go but there's an even easier option involving a simple loop.

```
def count_stair_ways(n):
    """ Some doc. Input can be any integer n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n + 1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

**Going further**

You sequence actually corresponds to [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). You'll find various super efficient way to compute them.

Answer (score 3):

This solution takes a problem of size *n* and decomposes it into two problems of approximately size *n* - 1.  The complexity would therefore be O(2<sup>*n*</sup>).  Furthermore, many of those computations would be performed over and over again, so the solution would benefit greatly from [memoization](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Comment: sure, i will add cache to store the results. I did similar problem [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/fibonacci-sum-with-memoization). My idea was to first appreciate the power of tree recursion.

Comment: @overexchange The problem is performance. Every function call the VM has to save a lot of data to the stack. This is slooow even for n=40, which is plausible. And you will run out of stack space for large n.

Answer (score 0):

To get style out of the way:

You should have a space after `==` in `if n ==2`.

---

You can combine the first two `if-else` statements into one statement with:

```
if n in (1, 2):
    return n
```

Like @200_success said, you should be caching your results, so that way, when you keeping increasing, you won't have  to recalculate every thing over and over.