# Count ways to reach the n’th stair

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I have solved [Leetcode climbing-stairs problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/) which is stated as:

> There are n stairs, a person standing at the bottom wants to reach the
>   top. The person can climb either 1 stair or 2 stairs at a time. Count
>   the number of ways, the person can reach the top.

I used dynamic programming to solve this like below:

```
class Solution(object):
    def climbStairs(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if n==1:
            return 1
        dp = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
        dp[1] = 1
        dp[2] = 2
        for i in range(3,n+1):
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2]
        return dp[n]
```

1. Is there any improvement of this code?
2. Is there any alternative way rather than dynamic programming?

Comment: Does the recursion formula remind you of some famous sequence? (Spoiler: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96197/staircase-problem-solved-using-recursion)

Comment: @MartinR, yes. It shows a lot of ways. Thanks a lot for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pythonic Ideas

**Multiplication with lists**

You can create an array of `n + 1` zeros using the `*` operator:

```
dp = [0] * (n + 1)
```

Which seems a bit clearer (IMHO) than:

```
dp = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
```

**General solution with no base case**

You could get rid of the base case `n == 1` if you do:

```
def climbStairs(self, n):
    """
    :type n: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    dp = [0] * max(3, n + 1)
    dp[1] = 1
    dp[2] = 2
    for i in range(3,n+1):
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2]
    return dp[n]
```

---

### Computing Fibonacci

Your solution is one of the fastest (and most obvious) ways to compute fibonacci with a running time of \$O(n)\$. However, there's a \$O(\log{}n)\$ solution using an interesting property of fibonacci numbers. Here's a [proof and an in depth explanation](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms).

Basically if you know `F(n)` and `F(n-1)` you can find `F(2n)` and `F(2n-1)` following these two formulas:

\begin{aligned}F_{2n-1}&=F_{n}^{2}+F_{n-1}^{2}\\F_{2n}&=(F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})F_{n}\\&=(2F_{n-1}+F_{n})F_{n}.\end{aligned}

Using this, you can double your way to the fibonacci number you need (or recursively half your way down)

```
def fibonacci(n):
    memo = {
        0: 0,
        1: 1,
        2: 1,
        3: 2
    }
    def recurse(n):
        if not n in memo:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                k = n // 2
                memo[k] = recurse(k)
                memo[k - 1] = recurse(k - 1)
                memo[n] = (2 * memo[k - 1] + memo[k]) * memo[k]
            else:
                k = (n + 1) // 2
                memo[k] = recurse(k)
                memo[k - 1] = recurse(k - 1)
                memo[n] = memo[k]**2 + memo[k -1]**2
        return memo[n]
    return recurse(n)
```

*Note: While the closed form solution is interesting, it's not computationally practical since it requires infinate precision of \$\phi\$.*